# Why are there no problems parameterized by basic graph properties (e.g. maximum clique and maximum degree)?

Tags: complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity

While trying to get an overview of parameters used in the parameterized-complexity theory, it seems that there are no problems parameterized by some basic graph properties like maximum clique, maximum independent set, and maximum degree. Among other resources, I've used this resource https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/par_27.html.

It seems that most problems studied in this field are parameterized by parameters obtained from decompositions (path-width, clique-width, etc). For instance, I know the tree-width parameter (which is perhaps the most used) seem to represent a global aspect of a graph very well when compared to maximum clique, maximum independent set, and maximum degree. But would that be a valid argument when trying to reason why using these is hard and why they are not used as parameters? If not, what would it be?

Comment: Well, they do get used in hardness results: Clique and Independent Set are both $\mathsf{W}[1]$-complete under fpt-reductions when parameterized by the corresponding sizes. Funnily enough, IS is fixed-parameter tractable when parameterized by $\operatorname{max} \{k, d\}$ where $k$ is the size of the largest IS and $d$ is the maximum degree. You can find these results in the book [Parameterized Complexity Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-29953-X)